# "На форте" или "на форту"?

Tags: склонение

Если я не ошибаюсь, то слово "**форт**" относится ко второму склонению. К этому же склонению относится слово "**мост**". Если взять две однотипные фразы: "*Я буду ждать на мосту в полдень*" и "*Я буду ждать на форту в полдень*", то вторая фраза - как-то режет слух. Посему, я бы и хотел уточнить, как же всё-таки правильно говорить/писать в этом случае: "**на форте**" или "**на форту**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, *форт* относится ко второму склонению, так же как и *мост*.  Произношение непривычно, режет слух, но словари, в частности "Русский орфографический словарь" под ред. В.В. Лопатина, в предложном падеже дают нормативное написание/произношение **о форте**, **в форту**, мн. -ы, -ов

Answer (score 2):

Насколько мне известно, вариант "на форту" до Лопатина не считался допустимым.
Тут вот какое дело. Форма предложного на "-у" - рудимент древнего местного падежа (локатива). К современным словам и поздним заимствованиям обычно неприменима. 
Не хочу спорить о нормативности "на форту" в современной речи, но по крайней мере это вполне объясняет Вашу настороженность.

А вообще эта форма очень скользкая. Только некоторые слова императивно требуют именно этой формы (подобные "на льду", "в полку"). Большинство - как минимум вариативны с обычной формой предложного: В меде - на меду, в цвету - в цвете и проч. Дальнейшее опускаю, но если интересно, продолжу.